# How to use xml entity reference in eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, entity

I'm trying to use XML entity reference in my workspace in Eclipse Indigo and am not able to refer the xml file as expected. I'm using the following syntax:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc 
[
 <!ENTITY planName SYSTEM "/planName.xml">
 <!-- planName.xml is in the same folder as the current xml i.e. C:\Users\Workspaces\projectA -->
]>

  <commands>    
    <name>&planName;</name> 
  </commands>
```

When i try to use this file, i get the following error:

```
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Desktop\Softwares\IndigoEclipse\planName.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

If on the other hand I give the absolute path of the xml file, I can use the file as expected

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc 
[
 <!ENTITY planName SYSTEM "C:\Users\Workspaces\projectA\planName.xml">
 <!-- absolute path of workspace executes normally -->
]>

  <commands>    
    <name>&planName;</name> 
  </commands>
```

Can i refer an entity without giving its absolute path in Eclipse?

Comment: What matters is the Java code, and not the IDE you have used to write it.

Comment: Thanks JB. I verified the code but I'm not sure if there is any security setting in the IDE that need to be tweaked in order to get this fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the slash from `SYSTEM "/planName.xml"`.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY planName SYSTEM "planName.xml">
<!-- planName.xml is in the same folder as the current xml i.e. C:\Users\Workspaces\projectA -->
]>
<commands>    
  <name>&planName;</name> 
</commands>
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but that doesn't help either.

In fact, i have tried out many variations of the address but it always takes the root folder as the eclipse installation path as i mentioned.